# Как можно сократить и оптимизировать запрос

Tags: оптимизация, sql

Собственно, интересует как можно сократить и оптимизировать данный запрос:

```
SELECT IF(friends.id1 = '$id', friends.id2, friends.id1) id, profiles.username
FROM friends, profiles
WHERE (friends.id1 = '$id' OR friends.id2 = '$id')
  AND (friends.id1 = profiles.id OR friends.id2 = profiles.id)
  AND NOT(id = '$id')
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде всего его нужно немного подправить по существу. Условие в WHERE составлено неверно.

Должно быть не так:

```
    (friends.id1 = '$id' OR friends.id2 = '$id')
AND (friends.id1 = profiles.id OR friends.id2 = profiles.id)
```

А так:

```
    (friends.id1 = '$id' AND friends.id2 = profiles.id)
 OR (friends.id2 = '$id' AND friends.id1 = profiles.id)
```

Comment: Как раз, должно быть OR:)

Comment: Поверьте! Должно быть именно так, как я написал. OR там тоже есть, но в другом месте.

Comment: @Shamov, извиняюсь)) Не заметил))

Answer (score 2):

Вот этот участок кода

```
AND NOT(id = '$id')
```

можно заменить на

```
AND id != '$id'
```